# Date query. > 2 weeks old

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a request table where customers log requests for products.

[Request table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNBxw.png)

It has a date column.
eg 2020/12/12

unfulfilled requests must be chased up after two weeks.

How would i query this?

I imagine it would be manually working out the date two weeks ago and querying requests older than that

```
SELECT `requests`.*
From `Requests`
Where `Requests`.`Date` < 2020/12/01
```

Am i on the right path?

Comment: Replace screenshot with well-formatted textual script. Use date literal in the format valid for MySQL (`YYYY-MM-DD`). Quote literal with `'` - now it is not date but arithmetic expression. *unfulfilled requests must be chased up after two weeks.* Add (or substract) INTERVAL 14 DAY to the CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: 2020 divided by 12 divided by 1 = 168.333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meet `DATE_SUB()` ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)).

```
SELECT requests.*
FROM requests
WHERE requests.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

That says: Get me all requests whose `date` is earlier than now minus two weeks (based on your databases's timezone).

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK` seems to be more clear...

Comment: You don't need to change data type. `DATE_SUB` is a function, not a data type. It works with data/time columns.